# 403 (rateLimitExceeded) for Core Reporting API v3

Tags: java, multithreading, google-analytics-api

We have a multi-threaded Java application, which pulls data from CoreV3 API.

We use RateLimiter from Guava and Semaphore from JDK to not reach the limit of 10 RPS per IP address and 10 concurrent requests for a profile.

Here's a code snippet:

---

```
private static final int MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 6;
private static final int MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND = 6;

private static final Semaphore SEMAPHORE = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS);
private static final RateLimiter RATE_LIMITER = RateLimiter.create(MAX_REQUESTS_PER_SECOND);

private <T extends GenericJson> T execute(AnalyticsRequest<T> request) throws IOException {
    try {
        SEMAPHORE.acquireUninterruptibly();
        RATE_LIMITER.acquire();
        return request.execute();
    } finally {
        SEMAPHORE.release();
    }
}
```

---

But when multiple threads getting 5XX error codes at the same time, all subsequent requests fall off with 403 (rateLimitExceeded) error for quite a while.

Every separate thread uses Exponential BackOff algorithm for re-sending failed requests.

How should we escape an issue with rateLimitExceeded, while continue using multi-threading?

Comment: You need a way to globally back off once you start getting `5XX`. You only get "10 failed `5XX` requests per hour" and "50 failed `5XX` requests per day" See the [limits and quotas page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_errors).

Comment: @Matt, thanks for a reply. Maybe, you also have a suggestion, how to do this (globally back off once I start getting 5XX)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the errors rate limit is specific to a view (profile), so perhaps store a shared array between all the threads of "troubled_views" as well as a separate global 5XX RateLimiter object. and if the intended request contains a viewId in that array of troubled_views wait for the 5XX RateLimiter semaphore to become available. I haven't done much multithreading in Java but hopefully the design idea gives you something to go on.

Comment: you can try adding a random quotaUser this used to work sometimes.   I tried to multi thread the API using C# a while ago I ended up removing it.  The API simply wont allow you to make more then 10 requests a second to the same ViewId.   However check out the V4 api that seams to allow for more requests per-second which might open up for multi-threading as an option.    Also Google recently added something that if you get to many 500 errors they block you for a while (no definition of a while) so its a bad idea to try and force it.

Comment: @DaImTo quotaUser will prevent us from getting `userRateLimitExceed` (which we never faced), but not from 5ХХ, which causing `403 rateLimitExceeded`.

Comment: Thing is that rateLimitExceeded is more of a current session based thing.   You could also consider moving to the Reporting API Google Analytics API v4 I think the quota is different.  I don't think I have gotten any 5XX errors after I switched to it.  I should try and multi thread it see if I can force something. sorry Matt :)

Comment: @DaImTo according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#write_error), quota seems to be the same. But, as I assume, servers for v3 and v4 are the same, so we would face the same problem with 5XX there too. We're planning to switch to v4 in the future (for another purpose), so we would test it out anyway. But, I just can't get the Googles' point: way users have to struggle with problems, which are caused by the google servers failures?.. (correct me, if I'm wrong).

Comment: I think the main reason for the 500 flood protection errors is that that they don't want people like us spamming the servers.   I had this discussion with the devs a few years ago when I started developing my application.   There opinion was we all need to share the server load even google does actually have a limited amount of server power.  If to many people are multi threading its going to slow things down for everyone.  So by keeping things "reasonable" they prevent any issues.

Comment: BTW try and enable a project using the Reporting API  in google developer console instead of Analytics API.  What does the quota say?